# Group Column values as row result in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have table prod and have three column id,name and maturity as shown below.

```
            id      name    maturity
            -------------------------------
            224     cash    1d
            224     cash    2d
            224     cash    3d
            224     cash    4d
            225     bond    5w
            225     bond    6w
            225     bond    7w
            225     bond    8w
```

Here i need the output like( i mean if i fire an sql statement)

```
            224     cash    1d,2d,3d,4d
            225     bond    5w,6w,7w,8w
```

can some oone please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

The [LISTAGG](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.in/2010/02/oracle-new-string-aggregation.html) function is what you are looking for (in Oracle 11g at least).

A full syntax example:

`SELECT id, name, LISTAGG(maturity, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY maturity)
 FROM   your_table
 GROUP BY id`

Note: You can also change the grouping condition to `GROUP BY name`, if needed.

Comment: Thanq for your quick responce, but here i am using 10g version

Comment: @AshokKumarDabbadi - then why did you tag the question with both 10g and 11g? [There are various methods for doing this in earlier versions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php), and plenty of questions here about it (many of which point to that article).